# Serving only image assets from CloudFront with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I recently switched to using CloudFront as a CDN to serve my assets using the simple

`config.action_controller.asset_host = "url of your cloudfront distribution"` in my config file.

All works well, CF pulls in assets that it doesn't have just fine, serves them just fine, is faster than using the asset pipeline.

However, for a variety of reasons, some of our JS breaks when served from CF and not our own server. So I am looking for a way to use CF just for image (or image/css) assets, and still serve the compiled application.js file directly from our own server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails allows you to set `config.action_controller.asset_host` to be a proc.  That way you can have as much control as you like over the selection of the asset host.  For example:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host =  Proc.new { |source|
  if source.ends_with?('.jpg')
    "http://cdn.example.com"
  else
    nil
  end
}
```

See the [api docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper) for more details.